# InspIRCd cmd_hostname_lookup module causes startup failure

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, irc

I'm trying to bring up an Ubuntu 12.04 IRC server running InspIRCd 2.0.14 but it fails to start due to some DNS errors while loading cmd_hostname_lookup.so and cmd_dns.so modules. I compiled it from the [insp20 branch](https://github.com/inspircd/inspircd/tree/insp20) on Github.

```
[*] Unable to load cmd_hostname_lookup.so: /usr/local/inspircd/modules/cmd_hostname_lookup.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Module10ReadConfigER12ConfigStatus
[*] Unable to load cmd_dns.so: /usr/local/inspircd/modules/cmd_dns.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Module13OnUserPreJoinEP9LocalUserP7ChannelRKSsRSsS5_
```

Everything was working fine in v2.1 but I recently downgraded to v2.0 for compatibility with Atheme. From what I can tell, this command module is used for resolving the hostnames of clients when they connect so I'm not sure why this would cause a startup failure. As a quick fix I removed both of these modules and everything started up fine. However, I'd like to figure out what is causing their load failure. Does anyone have any ideas as to what would cause this?

Comment: Did you use the old configuration file?

Comment: I copied over the configuration from the 2.1 instance

Comment: InspIRCd 2.1 has different modules than InspIRCd 2.0. Use the example configuration file from 2.0.